# Should I create resized images for all drawable folders (ldpi-mdpi-hdpi) if the image is the same?

Tags: android, image, hdpi, mdpi

If the image is the same but only resized, should I create (resize) all the images? Or let the system resize the images for me and only ship the app with hdpi images?

For me it makes sense to create new images if the images are different, for example, if the resized image doesn't fit into a ldpi screen then another image needs to be created with less information.

Am I going to run into memory issues on small devices if I only ship apps with hdpi images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use specific drawable for each type of screen. By doing this, you are sure that the UI is the same in each screens.

I don't know if you already read this but here is a good article that explains  the best way to support multiple screens http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html